# Python sentiment analysis from scratch best approach

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm starting a school project where I am free to do anything related to intelligent systems. I'm wanting to do something with twitter sentiment analysis. I've seen many tutorials online that use python with libraries such as NLTK or TextBlob, which make it easy to classify sentiment in text samples.

For this project I want to make my own neural net from scratch that I train and then can test using tweets from twitter's firehose API. I was thinking of using tflearn to create and train the network, as that's what I'm familiar with. The thing I'm not sure on is where to get my training/validation datasets from and how to prep that data for processing. What would you recommend I do to start?

Comment: You can also look into [Keras](https://keras.io/) for neural nets.

Answer (score 1):

If the main goal is Twitter Sentiment analysis, you can use a Lexical based approach instead of ML approach. Twitter being a social media domain, it is very difficult to find an ample amount of data for training the model.

I found lexical approach more convenient for Twitter sentiment analysis. Among all the lexical methods available VADER lexicon is developed based on tweets and I found it's working quite good for my project.

You can read about the research [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275828927_VADER_A_Parsimonious_Rule-based_Model_for_Sentiment_Analysis_of_Social_Media_Text).

The VADER researchers also developed a python library if at all your choice of language is Python. You can find the code with the detailed analysis [here](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment).

Hope this helps.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For data, you can use sentiment annotated dataset from any site, not twitter only. I recommend using [this](http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students/). This data is automatically annotated, so you need to inspect its labels to see if they are correct or not. See the link for more details
For sentiment analysis specifically, and any NLP problems generally, word embedding plays a vital role. I suggest you to use `word2vec` in `gensim` to convert your text data into numerical space.
Wish you the best for your project :D